# Short in front and short in back

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

I've stumbled upon Ray Bradbury's odd way of using prepositions in his book "Death is a lonely business".

> Cal, of course, had done that awful job. So I had several reasons to
>   go visit. Cal, the worst barber in Venice, maybe the world, but cheap,
>   called across the tidal waves of fog, waiting with his dull scissors,
>   brandishing his Bumblebee Electric clippers that shocked and stunned
>   poor writers and innocent customers who wandered in.
>   Cal, I thought. Snip away the darkness.
>   Short in front. So I can see.
>   Short on the sides. So I can hear.
>   Short in back. So I can feel things creeping up on me.

The way he asks the barber to cut his hair "short in front" and "short in back" maybe me really wonder if it is correct.

I'm used to "short at the front" and "short at the back".

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: I think it's more common to omit the article before "locative" prepositions of place like *back, front* in AmE. For example, I think Americans are more likely to say *Come out back* where Brits would say *Come out **the** back* (meaning *Come through the house to the back yard/garden with me*). Your cited example sounds very slightly "folksy" to me - but it's not particularly unusual, especially in relaxed spoken contexts.

Comment: *In front* sounds much more natural than *at the front* to this US English speaker, whether we're talking about hair, or a building, or anything except a battlefield, where "the front" has a very specific meaning, and you can be "at" it.  Hair, though, is just "in" front.

Comment: @stangdon You mentioned a battlefield. Isn't it correct to say "to fight in the front line" rather than "to fight at the front line"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've never heard anyone say "Come out back" I would have considered that to be bad English. Example: Come out the back of the bar.

Comment: @SovereignSun: I'm not sure how to address the implications of you as a non-native speaker telling me that you think the usage I've put forward is "bad English". It's informal, primarily AmE, and maybe a little bit "folksy", as I said. But it's far more common than [this Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Come+out+back+she%22) might imply (where I chose to append ***she*** to the search string to exclude "accidental collocation" matches). But note that the article is *very* unlikely to be omitted in contexts like your example, where ***back*** is further qualified.

Comment: (Actually, [*Come out back **with** (me/us/etc.)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Come+out+back+with%22) better reflects prevalence.)

Comment: @SovereignSun - You're correct, but *front* is an adjective in "in the front line" and a noun in "at the front"!  **at the front** works as a phrase all by itself, where it means "the foremost line or part of an armed force; the furthest position that an army has reached and where the enemy is or may be engaged."

Comment: @FumbleFingers - _I would have considered that to be bad English._ That sounds to me like the O.P. is learning something from you, not accusing you of using bad English. I'm sure a lot of things we native speakers say would sound like bad English to the learner the first time around.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have googled that and, yes, you're right, I'll know this now.

Comment: @J.R., SovereignSun: It's a tricky area, given that people have different definitions of "bad English". For example, *I'd've agreed wholeheartedly* if this sentence had written that example as *I would **of** agreed wholeheartedly*. Even though it's quite obvious that's what many native speakers *think* they're saying, and sometimes it's you can clearly hear the vowel as **ɒv** rather than just a schwa **əv**. By which I mean that just because a usage might be relatively widespread doesn't necessarily imply it can't be bad English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Mustn't that be *"I would have agreed wholeheartedly?"*

Comment: @SovereignSun: Exactly! But sadly, even though it's fairly obvious to relatively advanced "learners" such as yourself, there are certainly plenty of native speakers who get that one wrong. By the way, it may interest you to know that ***Mustn't** [something be true]?* is a fairly dated / literary / formal usage. Most native speakers would say ***Shouldn't** it be blah blah?*, or to specifically emphasise the *necessity*, they might say *Doesn't it **have** to be blah blah?* (with stressed ***have*** enunciated as ***haff***, if you want to sound like a *really* advanced learner! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I want to sound like an expert in the English language.

Comment: You might find [this ELU question of mine](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/) interesting. You'll see from "Edit1" and "Edit2" in the question text that even I learnt a few things from that one. If you have time to read all the comments you'll see that although most native speakers use these pronunciation changes in certain contexts, there are at least a few who don't even *recognise* them, let alone *use* them. Also note my first comment there: *...if you hear a non-native reproducing it correctly I think you probably uprate your opinion of their command of English*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I would use *in*, not *at*, when talking about the front and back of my hair. And, just as Bradbury did, I would use *on* for the sides.

I don't know how else this can be explained, except to assure you that it's indeed acceptable idiomatic speech and to remind you that most prepositions are not confined to a single meaning but have multiple meanings and usages. It's also not uncommon for more than one preposition to be acceptable in a given context (e.g., "He lives up/down the street from the store.")

In this particular case, either *in* or *at* is acceptable. Consider the way these two dictionaries define *mullet* (emphasis added):

> **[mullet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mullet)** (*n*.) a hairstyle in which the hair is short on the sides and top and long ***at*** the back
>   <sup>(source: Merriam-Webster)</sup>
>
> **[mullet](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=mullet)** (*n*.) A hairstyle formed by cutting the hair short on the top and sides of the head and allowing it to grow longer ***in*** back.
>   <sup>(source: American Heritage)</sup>

Comment: It might be the same sort of thing as "she was in the front/back of the room". But then we say "at the front of the line" - choosing "in", "on", or "at" can be difficult :(

Comment: You should consider taking a career in barbering @J.R.

Comment: Why is there no article then? Why not *in the front* and *in the back*? Where can I read about this?

Comment: @SovereignSun - Because the articles would be optional in this case. The sentence is neither wrong with them nor without them.

Comment: Now I'm really stuck here. Here it is "at the front" and "at the back" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mullet_(haircut) - Between 2006 and 2008, the mullet was in fashion among individuals of Lebanese descent in Australia. The style had already been popular with the bogan subculture. The fashion trend quickly waned by late 2009. This was the type of a mullet which had a crew cut at the front, top and sides, and long hair at the back.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/short_back_and_sides - A haircut in which the hair is cut short at the back and the sides. Here it is "Short at the back" and also "Short at the sides" instead of "Short on the sides"

Comment: http://hairstylesforchubbyfaces.com/haircuts-short-back-longer-front/ - Latest 50 Haircuts Short in Back Longer in Front. Here everywhere it is "short in back" and "longer in front".

Comment: http://www.livingly.com/Hairstyle+Tips/articles/bf9ej0OmAxp/Hair+Short+Front+Long+Back+Help+Styling - Do you need help styling hair short in front and long in back? Sounds like you have a mullet! Here it's also "short in front" and "long in back".

Comment: http://www.womanmagazine.co.uk/hair/short-crop-hairstyle-guide-28090 - Because short haircuts often take little styling but suit all hair types, even fine hair if you keep your layers longer at the front. Here it again is "longer at the front".

Comment: @SovereignSun - What is there to be confused about? **Sometimes you can use more than one preposition to mean the same thing**. You can tell your hairstylist that you want your hair cut or colored _in the back_ or _at the back_, and your stylist will understand either one just fine.